# How to disable decimal input for currency Inputmask

Tags: jquery, html, input-mask

I am currently using RobinHerbots input-mask: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

You can refer to the currency demo according to this page: http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/
and click the demo tab, then currency

I am trying to implement a similar currency mask with decimal input disable. So user will not able to press "." and move to decimal

for example:

[image]

the screenshot above is a perfect example. However, user can still use arrow keys or "." to navigate the cursor. Is there anyway to disable it?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `step="1"` ?

Comment: I set step="1" for the mask `'alias': 'currency', 'step': '1'` it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this 'digits': '0' configuration will fix the problem:

```
data-inputmask="'alias': 'currency', 'placeholder': '', 'digits': '0', 'allowMinus': 'false', 'showMaskOnFocus': 'false', 'showMaskOnHover': 'false'"
```

Comment: How to grouping it (1000000 -> 1.000.000)?

Comment: Where do I add this? Which file?